# Retrieving the data for an each element in the vector in R using a loop and assembling a new data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, vector, while-loop

I have a vector `crypto_coins <- c("bitcoin","polkadot","dogecoin")` and a function `return_chart("coin_name")`, which returns some data on a given crypto (e.g. `return_chart("bitcoin")`).

Daily prices in `return_chart` are stored in a column `prices`. For example:

`return_chart("bitcoin")[, "prices"] #returns every daily price of bitcoin for last 30 days`

I would like to create a FOR (or WHILE) loop, which would allow me to 1) retrieve the data for each currency in the vector and 2) assemble a new data frame `Crypto_data`.
This data frame should contain:

1. Coin names in the first column.
2. Average price (calculated as an average of daily prices) for each coin in the second column.
3. Standard deviation of the average price for each coin in the third column.

Please, let me know how can I create such a loop. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create the output data frame with initialised columns of zeros for average price and standard error:

```
crypto_coins <- c("bitcoin","polkadot","dogecoin")
df = data.frame(coin_name = crypto_coins, average = rep(0,length(crypto_coins)), SE = rep(0,length(crypto_coins)))
```

For each element of `crypto_coins`, you want to have an average and a SE. So you want a loop over the length of `crypto_coins`, collecting the mean and square root of the variance for each:

```
for (i in 1:length(crypto_coins))
{
  df$average[i] = mean(return_chart(crypto_coin[i])[,"prices"])
  df$SE[i] = sqrt(var(return_chart(crypto_coin[i])[,"prices"]))
}
```

Here `crypto_coin[i]` is the `i`th element of `crypto_coin`, and `df$average[i]` is the `i`th element of the `average` column of the `df` data frame. The `mean(x)` and `var(x)` functions compute the mean and the variance of a vector `x`.

---

---

More compactly, this can be written by using `sapply()`:

```
averages <- sapply(1:length(crypto_coins), function(x) mean(return_chart(crypto_coin[x])[,"prices"]))
SEs <- sapply(1:length(crypto_coins), function(x) sqrt(var(return_chart(crypto_coin[x])[,"prices"])))
df = data.frame(coin = crypto_coins, average = averages, SE = SEs)
```